# Local request to port 80 via domain name

Tags: iis-8.5

I'm running a Windows 2012 IIS 8.5 listening on port 80 to requests coming to domain www.mydomain.com, which I have set in my DNS to the server IP.

Everything **works fine outside**, but for whatever reason, when I request that domain from a browser inside the server, it does not respond.

I have tried `telnet www.mydomain.com 80` from inside the server and it returns Connection Error. If I try `telnet localhost 80` it works.

As I said, from outside the server, everything works fine, telnet connects, and the web is served without any problem.

Also, if

Comment: I can't find a specific question that this duplicates, but it surely is (edit: found it). The whatever-reason is that your router doesn't support, or isn't configured for, hairpin NAT, and the possible fixes are to: configure it for hairpin NAT, replace it for one that does support it, or use split-DNS so the name resolves differently internally and externally. (and `mydomain.com` is owned by a domain hosting company in America. Please use [example.com](http://example.com/) for examples, it's reserved for that use).

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler The question has insufficient information to say for sure whether it is a duplicate of that question or not. But that just means there is another applicable close reason as well.

Comment: @kasperd I guess it's possible that user1437071 has put their domain in /etc/hosts with some random, unrelated IP address in it...